# php session value losing while moving to one page to another

Tags: php, session

I have made a simple website in which user can log in.my problem is when a user enter the address `http://www.mysite.com/signin.php` and after a successful log in he manually enters the address as `http://mysite.com` but from that page session variable is not getting. How do I make same session  to both `www.mysite.com,mysite.com` Are there any settings in the php ini file or how do I manage to make same session to both addresses?

```
if(verify($password,$pw['password']))
{   

    $uid=$pw['user_id'];
    $_SESSION['login_status']=true;
    $_SESSION['user']=$uid;
```

}
i have a page checksession.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

when i login from http://www.mysite.com/signin.php and checking http://www.mysite.com/checksession.php its showing session values but from http://mysite.com/checksession.php it showing nothing.(differance is in address one with www,another without www)

Comment: Please show some code so that we can understand your problem and help...Show the code in which you set your session and login page + login redirect page

Comment: You should only use `mysite.com` or `www.mysite.com` not both. Please refer to http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139066 to understand why

Comment: Why cannot you just use a consistent domain name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually force www. or no www. in my .htaccess file using redirects.

Your problem is probably your PHP_SESS_ID cookie domain not beginning with a "."

```
session_set_cookie_params ( 3600 , '/', '.example.com');
```

That should set it.

Comment: call this after session_start()

Answer (score 1):

Add this line before your `session_start();`:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.mysite.com' );
```

This should tell PHP to include all subdomains of mysite.com in the same session, including 'www'. Note the period before the domain name.

Answer (score 0):

A different Approach is to use session_start(); inside config.php file and include that file on the top of the code of every page where sessions are required otherwise U will not be able to get the value of SESSION variable..!!

Answer (score -1):

use *https://*  before the page address call..